# Can this code with NumPy calculations be more efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert `array a` to log_e. If the number to be converted is non-positive, then convert it to 0:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1,0,1,2])
b = np.zeros(len(a))
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] <= 0:
        b[i] = 0
    else:
        b[i] = np.log(a[i])
```

To improve the computing performance, I think the following is better. But then the error `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` pops out. Can I use some code to carry on with my expected calculations?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,1,2])
b = np.log(a)
```

Comment: Use `np.where` with a mask : `np.where(a<=0, 0, np.log(a))`. You would still get that warning though.

Answer (score 2):

use `np.where` on `a` to mask non-positive number with `1`, then `np.log`:

```
b = np.log(np.where(a>0, a, 1))
```

Output:

```
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.69314718])
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a "ufunc", `numpy.log` accepts the parameters `where` and `out`.  So an efficient method for your computation is as follows.

```
In [6]: a = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2])
```

Create the output array.

```
In [7]: b = np.zeros(len(a))
```

Tell `numpy.log` to only compute the result where `a > 0`, and put the output in `b`.  This returns the array given as `out`, and modifies `out` (i.e. `b`) in-place.

```
In [8]: np.log(a, where=a > 0, out=b)
Out[8]: array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.69314718])

In [9]: b
Out[9]: array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.69314718])
```